# New Intel processors KPTI bug. Which slowdown to expect for floating point computation?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, intel, processor

Some media have reported that a [new hardware bug](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/02/intel_cpu_design_flaw/) in Intel processors,  allowing user mode processes to access kernel mode memory, has been discovered:

> It is understood the bug is present in modern Intel processors
>   produced in the past decade. It allows normal user programs – from
>   database applications to JavaScript in web browsers – to discern to
>   some extent the layout or contents of protected kernel memory areas.
>
> The effects [of fixes] are still being benchmarked, however we're
>   looking at a ballpark figure of five to 30 per cent slow down,
>   depending on the task and the processor model.

After the bug is fixed, which slowdown am I to expect for multicore floating point computations?

Comment: Related: you can disable the workaround on machines that *never* run any untrusted code (e.g. cluster compute nodes *might* consider this, if you trust all of your users not to take over the machine on purpose, or run any untrusted code by accident).  https://askubuntu.com/questions/991874/how-to-disable-page-table-isolation-to-regain-performance-lost-due-to-intel-cpu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, only the performance of switches between kernel and user mode are affected. For example, handling a lot of I/O is a workload where this is frequent, but CPU-intensive processes should not be affected as much.

To quote from one article that analyzes performance of the Linux KPTI patch:

> Most workloads that we have run show single-digit regressions. 5% is a good round number for what is typical. The worst we have seen is a roughly 30% regression on a loopback networking test that did a ton of syscalls and context switches.
>
> ...
>
> So PostgreSQL SELECT command is about ~20% slower with KPTI workaround, and I/Os in general seem to be impacted negatively according to Phoronix benchmarks especially with fast storage, but not gaming performance, Linux kernel compilation, H.264 encoding, etc…

Source: https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/01/03/intel-hardware-security-bug-fix-to-hit-performance-on-windows-linux/

So, if your FP computations rely mostly on in-memory data shifting and not I/O, they should be mostly unaffected.

Comment: There are already some tests on https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-415-x86pti

Comment: The article I linked quoted form the same source.